# Customize Expandable List Android

Tags: android, list, customization

This is what my application looks like using expanable listview to read data from database and then displaying it, the range is for 3 month or 12 weeks! now what i want is to display only content of every week !! i dont want to display the WEEK label! for example if there is any data during this 12 weeks we will display it ( but just with day label and data description) but if not we want to display nothing!! ( not display the Weeks!) and also i want to  disable the collapsing of each item.

[image]

this is my adapter

```
public class MyCareHeaderExpandableListAdapter extends MyCareExpandableListAdapter {

public MyCareHeaderExpandableListAdapter(Context context) {
    super(context);
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //Log.d("getChildView", "getChildView " + groupPosition);
     //View view = adapter.getView(childPosition, convertView, parent);
    Item item = getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    return setContentView(R.layout.expandable_list_item, convertView, item);
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------
@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    int id = ((ScheduleItem)m_childrens.get(groupPosition).getItem(childPosition)).getID();
    return id;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * This function is called to generate the view for the groups.
 */
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String name[] = getGroup(groupPosition);

    //  Generating header
    //  A header has no child, and begins the name with "Week"
    //if (getChildrenCount(groupPosition) == 0 && (name[1] == null)) { 
    if (name[1] == null) { 
        convertView = m_inflater.inflate(R.layout.expandable_list_week, null);
        TextView textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtHeader);
        Font.setToView(textView, Font.BOLD);
        textView.setText(name[0]);
    }
    //  Generating group name
    else {
        //Log.d("getGroupView", name);
        convertView = m_inflater.inflate(R.layout.expandable_list_group, null); 
        TextView textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtDay);
        textView.setText(name[0]);
        Font.setToView(textView, Font.BOLD);

        TextView textView2 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
        textView2.setText(name[1]);
        Font.setToView(textView2, Font.BOLD);
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues you are dealing with:

(1) don't display group view for weeks with no entries

For this, I suggest modifying your group cursor query such that it does not return a cursor with entries for "empty" weeks.

(2) don't allow users to collapse groups

For this same purpose, I implemented the `OnGroupClickListener` to intercept the group clicks and essentially do nothing with it.  This allows me to control when the groups are expanded or collapsed.  Here my listener implementation:

```
/**
 * Only purpose here is to intercept taps on the header rows and ignore them
 * (avoid expandable list view adapter from expanding/collapsing).
 */
@Override
public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
        int groupPosition, long id) {
    return true;
}
```

**Edit:**

To have all the groups expanded:

```
    int groupCount = myCursorTreeAdapter.getGroupCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < groupCount; i++) {
        myExpandableListView().expandGroup(i);
    }
```

Comment: for second one i already tried this...this works for disabling touch on groups but the problem is , it only displays todays childs(events)!! for other days group is closed and ofcourse we can do nothing with it cause it is already disabled!! , as u can see on the picture in my first post! it shows the todays events but the other ones have events that we cannot see!!

Comment: Let me see if I understand correctly: (1) you do not want to see the week number, (2) you only want to display dates (days) when that date has at least one entry, and (3) all days with entries should show the entries.  Did I get that right?

Comment: Now i solved the problem for NOT SHOWING WEEKS!! the only thing is i want the expandable list to be always open! i mean i dont want to click the parent to Collapse, i want it to always display its childs

Comment: I added the code to expand all the groups.  That combined with the `onGroupClick` method will have the groups expanded and not allow them to be collapsed.